# Maven not displaying in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Recently i have installed m2e maven container plugin in eclipse. After installing, i couldn't see Maven dependencies and maven options. when i select pom.xml and right click, there is no maven run option. i got XSL Transformation...how to remove this?  I wnat to use maven targets . Also i couldn't select the existing maven project from source as there is no maven option is displaying.. please help me to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do right click on `Project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project`

After of that you will see `maven` options under `Run As` menu...

Or from your terminal you can try to convert you project:

```
cd ~/workspace/myProject/
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: No need to convert as maven Project. Already my project was maven project only and it was running perfectly before that updates. Also I dont see any option as ""Convert to Maven Project".

Comment: yes, I suggested that because is possible that eclipse can't recognize the project structure, but is odd that eclipse can't display maven options